# VPN route on Windows

Tags: windows, vpn

I'm trying to manually add a route to the VPN connection.
The reason is that when i connect to the VPN, i can't navigate the internet.
I've tried to uncheck the "Use default gateway on remote network" by going in properties of the vpn connection, then tcp/ipv4 - advanced. The result is that now i can surf the internet but can't communicate with other clients connected to the VPN (i've tried by using the ping command in both cases). i've read that i should use the route add command to make it work. let's assume that the destination IP of the VPN is 1.2.3.4, how should i write the command? i tried

```
route -p add 1.2.3.4 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.11
```

where 1.2.3.4 is the public ip of the pc on which the VPN server is hosted, 255.255.255.0 is it's subnet, and 192.168.0.11 is the static ip that my pc (that should connect to the VPN) uses.
Of course, this solution doesn't work.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

No, you should use:

```
route -p add 1.2.3.4 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.11
```

where:

`1.2.3.4` = subnet you want to reach. e.g. a server you want to reach has 192.168.1.123, then you use 192.168.1.0 (if you're in a /24)

`255.255.255.0` = subnet mask, obviously.

`192.168.0.11` = IP Address of the VPN Server gateway

if you don't know `192.168.0.11` then use "Use default gateway on remote network" and look at the routes you have then...

Comment: I'don't really understand... so if the VPN server has the following details: IP address 1.2.3.4, Subnet mask 255.255.255.0 and default gateway 192.168.1.1, then i should write: route -p add 192.168.1.1 mask 255.255.255.0 1.2.3.4? is that what you mean?